# esp8266 sensor data to raspberry pi webserver

Tags: php, arduino, apache2, iot, esp8266

im going to make an outdoor weather station with an esp8266 and a Raspberry Pi 3. The ESP should send the sensor data to the Raspberry Pi and save it in a text file. Both devices are connected to the same Wifi but the esp wont connect with the raspberry. I would be very happy if u can help me.
This is my Arduino Code:

```
#include <DHT_U.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

WiFiClient client;


#define DHTPIN 5
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

const char* ssid = "WLAN";
const char* passwort = "secret";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Verbindung wird aufgebaut mit ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, passwort);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(100);
    Serial.print(".");
   }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi verbunden");
  Serial.println("Lokale IP Adresse: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  WiFiClient client;

  dht.begin();
  delay(2000);
  float temp = dht.readTemperature();
  Serial.println("Temperatur gelesen:");
  Serial.println(temp);
  Serial.println(" Grad");
  float feuchte = dht.readHumidity();
  Serial.println("Feuchtigkeit gelesen:");
  Serial.println(feuchte);
  Serial.println(" %");

  IPAddress server(192, 168,1, 63);
  Serial.println(server);

  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("Mit Server verbunden! Sende Daten...");
    client.print("GET /sensor/sensor.php?st=");
    client.print(temp);
    client.print("&sh=");
    client.print(feuchte);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.1.63");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    delay(100);
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Daten erfolgreich verschickt!");
    }
    if(client.connected()) {
      client.stop();
     }

   else  {
    Serial.println("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen");
   }  

  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Gehe schlafen für 10 Sek");
  delay(1000);
  //ESP.deepSleep(10e6);
  }
  void loop() {
  // nothing here 
  }
```

and the php file on the Raspberry Pi:

```
<?php
    $temp = $_GET[“st“];
    $hum = $_GET[“sh“];
   $lineitem = $temp."\n".$hum."\n";
    $datei = fopen("/tmp/ext_values.dat","w");
    fwrite($datei, $lineitem);
    fclose($datei);
   echo "fine";
 ?>
```

Comment: You have wrong quotation character in `“st“`, don't use `“`, use `"`.

Comment: I will try ty it later ty

Comment: Still wont work @hcheung